# How to detect image feature with java opencv?

Tags: java, android, opencv

i like to make feature detections using java android studio and in these past few day, i had been stuck on how to detect this kind of image using opencv.

Cause its my first time using openCV and the only document i can read is not really helpfull. I've already convert it to grayscale. The big questions mark is how can i make my apps to recognize the feature of this image.

[image]

so,for example i can make the label of this image as "abstractimage", so when i foto some of another image with the same pattern it will be detected as "abstractimage", but the detected image will be using on t-shirt, and random object with the same image based on this feature image. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Classification and labelling of images according to the example you gave are clearly ML problems. You probably want to check out Tensorflow Lite https://www.tensorflow.org/lite

Comment: thats good, i liked to try it for later. But i have some project for my college that should be using opencv right now that's why... if you found something about opencv i hope you share it to me brother